# How do I select everything in a list after the first occurence of?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection where each element has a property called IsTop. What I want to do is use linq (if possible) to select everything after the first occurence of IsTop == true. Right now, I do this like this:

```
bool[] foundTop = {false}; // use array for modified closure
foreach (var config in fullHierarchy
    .Where(config => config.IsTop || foundTop[0]))
{
    foundTop[0] = true;
    configurationHierarchy.Add(config);
}
```

I feel like this is a bit contrived. Is there a simpler way to achieve this in LINQ?

Comment: You're saying *after the first occurrence of top*, so how do you determine ordering in your collection?

Comment: The ordering is handled in a datasource as it is read out of a database.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
var afterTop = fullHierarchy.SkipWhile(x => !x.IsTop).Skip(1);
```

The `SkipWhile` skips all elements until the first item is found where `IsTop == true`, then the `Skip` skips that element, too. The result will be all items in `fullHierarchy` *after* the first one where `IsTop == true`.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
var result = fullHierarchy.SkipWhile(x=>!x.IsTop).Skip(1);
```

Answer (score 4):

I think that [`SkipWhile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549075%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is what you're looking for, e.g.

```
var myArray = new[]
{
    new { IsTop = false, S = 'a' },
    new { IsTop = true, S = 'b' },
    new { IsTop = false, S = 'c' },
};
myArray.SkipWhile(x => !x.IsTop); // contains the elements with 'b' and 'c'

// in your code, might be
foreach (var config in fullHierarchy.SkipWhile(x => !x.IsTop))
{
    configurationHierarchy.Add(config);
}
```